# WinForms embed in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have built an **asp.net website** and a **C# desktop application**. My client requires me to **embed the C# app** into a the website. I am aware that, this is only possible with the `windows control library.`

I gave it a try on that! But, that too didnt work out. It didnt work out on IE browser too.

Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried? I fail to understand it now.

Comment: i found this article please refer i am not sure 100% give it a try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne

Comment: *detailed 
I guess you have understood the part of apps that i have developed..
Now, the question is how to integrate the Winforms into the asp.net page..??
Should I be more precise??

Comment: Either you wan't to host the windows app in the browser (bad idea) or you'll have to rewrite the user interface into a new asp.net application (good idea). Hosting the windows app can only be done if you 'control' the end user machines and can force them to use specific browser and security settings.

Comment: The app doesn't contain any interactions with the database. I just want the app to do the normal functions as it would do being a desktop app on the Webpage too..

Comment: I had tried this article http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx
But, it was still the same...disappointment!!!

Comment: try to go for wpf xbap; i think it's good

Comment: hmmm, im working on it..

Answer (score 0):

1 You can `register such as ActiveX control` in .Net, and call this component from Web Application.

Link (RegSrv32) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx

2 You can convert to Sylverlight Application

3 You can  also just call Process, in order to access features